# Use jQuery to update attribute of HTML string in each() loop

Tags: jquery

I have an HTML string that I'm trying to update attributes on, but I can't seem to see the changes. Here is a simplified **example:**

```
var source = '<html><head></head><body><img src="abc" /><img src="abc" /></body></html>';

$(source).filter('img').each(function () {
    $(this).attr('src', '123');
});

// At this point if I look at source in a debugger 
// I'd expect to see the src attributes as all being 
// '123', but I still see them all as 'abc'.
```

How should this be written so that source is updated with the changes?

Comment: Since it sounds like it may help, what I am trying to do is to download the source code of a web page, make some updates to it, and then display it in an iframe. So I'm basically trying to make some changes to the HTML before I update the iframe. I could do this all with string functions, but jQuery would be much simpler and more robust.

Comment: What I'm trying to do exactly is download the source of a web page on another site and show it in an iframe on my site. To get it to look right, I need to make all of the relative paths (img, script, style, etc.) absolute pointing back to the original site. These updates need to occur in the head, body, etc. So I was hoping to be able to take the source of the other sites web page as a string, manipulate it, and then put it into an iframe on my site.

Answer (score 2):

This should work fine, but you need to reassign the html to the string back again or append to the DOM as the change doesn't make any effect here as selector is not a DOM element but a string.

```
var source = '<html><head></head><body><img src="abc" /><img src="abc" /></body></html>';
     var $source = $(source);
     $source.filter('img').each(function () {
             $(this).attr('src', '123');
        });
    console.log($source.wrapAll($('<div/>')).parent().html()); 
    //or
    source = $source.wrapAll($('<div/>')).parent().html();
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4rDKm/)**

Or just do

```
 $(source).filter('img').attr('src', function () {
      return '123';
   }).appendTo('someselector');
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HtKJj/)**

*note instead of using an explicit .each you can make use of function argument for `attr` as in the second example.*

Comment: Thanks for the response, you're giving me some hope it can be done. When I use your example and look at the final value of source, I do see that the image attributes have been changed. The only problem is that all of the HTML surrounding the images is gone, I only see the img tags (even if I switch from filter to find).

Comment: Like I said in my response, the HTML interpreter strips out anything outside of the body tag, including the body tag itself. You can only have 1 html element and 1 body in your document and those are created when the page loads.

Comment: @user1090698 Can you give an insight on why you need html, head, body tags on it?

Comment: @user1090698 as far as i know, You cannot create a html, head, body elements with jquery, what you are seeing is a string. so if you want them then append them to the result of .html().

Comment: @user1090698 here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/CW5NM/ you can do this way instead.

Comment: Thanks for the work around. I may be able to put together something based on it. If I can I'll mark this as the answer, unless another cleaner way comes along.

Comment: @user1090698 Sure. Sorry i am not able to think of another way.

Answer (score 2):

Jquery uses an array of elements behind the scenes. In your example, this array looks something like `['html']` (in pseudo code), meaning that you only have one element (html). When you use filter, it takes this array removes all the elements that don't match your selector. For example, if you had a list of elements like this: `['div', 'img', 'div', 'img']`, using your original code

```
var only_images = $(source).filter('img');
```

would result in `['img', 'img']` having removed all of the `'div'` tags. That being said, since your example only has one element `['html']`, the result ends up being an empty array `[]`.

The `find` method, however, searches all of the descendents for a match. That means every element in your string is matched against `img` (except for the original parent element `html`).

I don't know that I've done a good job of explaining it, but what you ultimately need to do is switch your code up and start using the `find` method. Example code below:

```
var source = '<html><head></head><body><img src="abc" /><img src="abc" /></body></html>';

$(source).find('img').each(function () {
    $(this).attr('src', '123');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, the explanation was great on the difference between filter and find. The problem is that even with find I don't see an updated value for source after the code exectutes.

Comment: I ran your original code. It looks like the HTML interpreter strips out everything that's not between the body tags. That means `$(source)` ends up being `['img', 'img']`, so `find` won't work because it only looks at descendants (and not the original elements). However, having said that, your original code seems to work fine. I'm curious, what makes you think the src isn't being updated?

Comment: I'm still fairly new to jQuery so I could be missing something obvious, but here is an example of what I'm seeing http://jsfiddle.net/yDGsK/

Comment: Ahhh. I see the problem. `source` is your original markup in text form.

Comment: Whoops, hit enter too soon. Let me make a fiddle for you real quick.

Comment: Not perfect but I think it gets the point across. http://jsfiddle.net/THEtheChad/GHePb/1/

Comment: `$(source)` turns the string into a DOM object which is now encapsulated in the jQuery object. `source != $(source)`. You have to extract the contents of `$(source)` somehow if you want to see any of the changes. In my example, I just appended it to the `body` then copied the HTML. There's many other methods to do this.

Comment: Alright so it sounds like there is no way to get the full HTML then as PSL mentioned, do you agree? In your example we just alert the body. I'll add one more comment on my original post about what I'm trying to achieve just to clarify the problem. Thanks a lot for your help so far...